# Complete destructive interference of light

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, electromagnetic-radiation, interference, superposition

[image: example]

in the below image,will there be complete destructive interference when s4 is placed in front of s3 and where does that energy go.can it be extracted from the system.

Comment: You could say that $S3$ was a source of light and $S4$ a perfect absorber of the light from $S3$.

Comment: I don't understand, two sources can form an interference pattern (a sequence of minima and maxima), they do not just cancel out each other globally...